# RoR push rejected to Heroku "Could not detect rake tasks"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, sass, rubygems

I'm trying to push some modifications of my Ruby on Rails web to Heroku but it says "push rejected". The error comes after "Detecting rake tasks" and here's the message:

```
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     LoadError: cannot load such file -- sass
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:258:in `load_dependency'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-5.1.4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:292:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:48:in `configure_sass'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:13:in `load!'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:78:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/config/application.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/Rakefile:6:in `require'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/Rakefile:6:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
remote:  !     /tmp/build_6bd938d1e4b5daac679d06adc0d16a99/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.3.0/gems/rake-13.0.1/exe/rake:27:in `<top (required)>'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `load'
remote:  !     vendor/bundle/bin/rake:29:in `<main>'
```

Just in case it was my modifications' fault, I deleted my local project, cloned it from heroku, changed just a comment and tried to push it. But the same error appeared. Which is weird, because my website is working ok in Heroku, but it gives an error if I try to upload the same code which is hosted there and working.

As the message error suggests, I also executed `bundle exec rake -P RAILS_ENV=production` and it gave me the following result with no error at all:

```
rake about
    environment
rake app:template
    environment
rake app:templates:copy
rake app:update
    update:configs
    update:bin
    update:upgrade_guide_info
rake app:update:bin
rake app:update:configs
rake app:update:upgrade_guide_info
rake assets:clean
    environment
rake assets:clobber
    environment
rake assets:environment
rake assets:precompile
    environment
    yarn:install
rake cache_digests:dependencies
    environment
rake cache_digests:nested_dependencies
    environment
rake cloudinary:sync_static
rake db:_dump
rake db:abort_if_pending_migrations
    environment
    load_config
rake db:charset
    environment
    load_config
rake db:check_protected_environments
    environment
    load_config
rake db:collation
    environment
    load_config
rake db:create
    load_config
rake db:create:all
    load_config
rake db:drop
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:drop:_unsafe
    load_config
rake db:drop:all
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:environment:set
    environment
    load_config
rake db:fixtures:identify
    environment
    load_config
rake db:fixtures:load
    environment
    load_config
rake db:forward
    environment
    load_config
rake db:load_config
rake db:migrate
    environment
    load_config
rake db:migrate:down
    environment
    load_config
rake db:migrate:redo
    environment
    load_config
rake db:migrate:reset
    db:drop
    db:create
    db:migrate
rake db:migrate:status
    environment
    load_config
rake db:migrate:up
    environment
    load_config
rake db:populate
    environment
rake db:purge
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:purge:all
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:reset
    db:drop
    db:setup
rake db:rollback
    environment
    load_config
rake db:schema:cache:clear
    environment
    load_config
rake db:schema:cache:dump
    environment
    load_config
rake db:schema:dump
    environment
    load_config
rake db:schema:load
    environment
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:schema:load_if_ruby
    db:create
    environment
rake db:seed
rake db:setup
    db:schema:load_if_ruby
    db:structure:load_if_sql
    seed
rake db:structure:dump
    environment
    load_config
rake db:structure:load
    environment
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:structure:load_if_sql
    db:create
    environment
rake db:test:load
    db:test:purge
rake db:test:load_schema
    db:test:purge
rake db:test:load_structure
    db:test:purge
rake db:test:prepare
    environment
    load_config
rake db:test:purge
    environment
    load_config
    check_protected_environments
rake db:version
    environment
    load_config
rake default
    test
rake dev:cache
rake environment
rake haml:erb2haml
rake initializers
    environment
rake log:clear
rake middleware
    environment
rake notes
rake notes:custom
rake notes:fixme
rake notes:optimize
rake notes:todo
rake paperclip:clean
    environment
rake paperclip:find_broken_attachments
    environment
rake paperclip:refresh
    paperclip:refresh:metadata
    paperclip:refresh:thumbnails
rake paperclip:refresh:fingerprints
    environment
rake paperclip:refresh:metadata
    environment
rake paperclip:refresh:missing_styles
    environment
rake paperclip:refresh:thumbnails
    environment
rake railties:install:migrations
    db:load_config
rake restart
rake routes
    environment
rake secret
rake stats
rake test
rake test:controllers
    test:prepare
rake test:db
    db:test:prepare
    test
rake test:functionals
    test:prepare
rake test:generators
    test:prepare
rake test:helpers
    test:prepare
rake test:integration
    test:prepare
rake test:jobs
    test:prepare
rake test:mailers
    test:prepare
rake test:models
    test:prepare
rake test:prepare
rake test:run
    test
rake test:system
    test:prepare
rake test:units
    test:prepare
rake time:zones
rake time:zones:all
rake time:zones:local
rake time:zones:us
rake tmp
rake tmp/cache
rake tmp/cache/assets
rake tmp/pids
rake tmp/sockets
rake tmp:cache:clear
rake tmp:clear
    tmp:cache:clear
    tmp:sockets:clear
rake tmp:create
    tmp/cache
    tmp/sockets
    tmp/pids
    tmp/cache/assets
rake tmp:pids:clear
rake tmp:sockets:clear
rake users:avisar_entrenadores_suscripcion
    environment
rake users:avisar_rutinas_vacias
    environment
rake users:eliminar_no_confirmados
    environment
rake yarn:install
```

Here's my Rakefile:

```
require File.expand_path('../config/application', __FILE__)

KeepMeFit::Application.load_tasks
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.3.3'

gem 'rails', '5.1.4'

group :development, :test do
    gem 'sqlite3'
    gem 'activemodel'
    gem 'json'
    gem 'rails_real_favicon'
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem 'guard-rspec'
    gem 'rb-notifu'
end

group :production do
    gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'
end

group :test do
    gem 'capybara'
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.1.0'
    gem 'launchy'
end

group :development do
    gem 'annotate'
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller'
    gem 'meta_request'
    gem 'certified', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails'
  gem 'coffee-rails'
  gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.8.0'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.12', platforms: [:ruby, :x64_mingw, :mingw]
gem 'puma'
gem 'haml'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
require 'rbconfig'
gem 'wdm', '>= 0.1.0' if RbConfig::CONFIG['target_os'] =~ /mswin|mingw/i
gem 'modernizr-rails'
gem 'sprockets-rails', :require => 'sprockets/railtie'
gem 'bootstrap-datepicker-rails'
gem 'tzinfo-data'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.1.0'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate'
gem 'friendly_id'
gem 'gon'
gem 'cloudinary'
gem "omniauth-google-oauth2"
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'omniauth-twitter'
gem 'figaro'
gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.6'
gem 'audited'
gem 'recaptcha', require: 'recaptcha/rails'
gem "chartkick"
gem "select2-rails"
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'braintree'
gem 'data-confirm-modal'
gem "paperclip", "~> 5.2.1"
gem 'aws-sdk', '< 3.0'
gem "remotipart"
gem 'cookies_eu'
gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'countries'
```

And my Gemfile.lock:

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (~> 0.6.1)
    actionmailer (5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      actionview (= 5.1.4)
      activejob (= 5.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (5.1.4)
      actionview (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      rack (~> 2.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
    actionview (5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.3)
    activejob (5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
    activerecord (5.1.4)
      activemodel (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      arel (~> 8.0)
    activesupport (5.1.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (~> 0.7)
      minitest (~> 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 1.1)
    addressable (2.5.2)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 4.0)
    annotate (2.7.2)
      activerecord (>= 3.2, < 6.0)
      rake (>= 10.4, < 13.0)
    arel (8.0.0)
    audited (4.5.0)
      activerecord (>= 4.0, < 5.2)
    autoprefixer-rails (7.1.6)
      execjs
    aws-sdk (2.11.1)
      aws-sdk-resources (= 2.11.1)
    aws-sdk-core (2.11.1)
      aws-sigv4 (~> 1.0)
      jmespath (~> 1.0)
    aws-sdk-resources (2.11.1)
      aws-sdk-core (= 2.11.1)
    aws-sigv4 (1.0.2)
    aws_cf_signer (0.1.3)
    bcrypt (3.1.12-x86-mingw32)
    better_errors (2.4.0)
      coderay (>= 1.0.0)
      erubi (>= 1.0.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.0)
    binding_of_caller (0.7.3)
      debug_inspector (>= 0.0.1)
    bootstrap-datepicker-rails (1.7.1.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    bootstrap-sass (3.3.7)
      autoprefixer-rails (>= 5.2.1)
      sass (>= 3.3.4)
    bootstrap-will_paginate (1.0.0)
      will_paginate
    braintree (2.80.1)
      builder (>= 2.0.0)
    builder (3.2.3)
    callsite (0.0.11)
    capybara (2.15.4)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (>= 1.3.3)
      rack (>= 1.0.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.5.4)
      xpath (~> 2.0)
    carrierwave (1.2.2)
      activemodel (>= 4.0.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16)
    certified (1.0.0)
    chartkick (2.2.5)
    climate_control (0.2.0)
    cloudinary (1.8.1)
      aws_cf_signer
      rest-client
    cocaine (0.5.8)
      climate_control (>= 0.0.3, < 1.0)
    coderay (1.1.2)
    coffee-rails (4.2.2)
      coffee-script (>= 2.2.0)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
    coffee-script (2.4.1)
      coffee-script-source
      execjs
    coffee-script-source (1.8.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.0.5)
    cookies_eu (1.7.1)
      js_cookie_rails (~> 2.2.0)
    countries (2.1.4)
      i18n_data (~> 0.8.0)
      money (~> 6.9)
      sixarm_ruby_unaccent (~> 1.1)
      unicode_utils (~> 1.4)
    country_select (3.1.1)
      countries (~> 2.0)
      sort_alphabetical (~> 1.0)
    crass (1.0.2)
    data-confirm-modal (1.6.1)
      railties (>= 3.0)
    debug_inspector (0.0.3)
    diff-lcs (1.3)
    domain_name (0.5.20170404)
      unf (>= 0.0.5, < 1.0.0)
    erubi (1.7.0)
    erubis (2.7.0)
    execjs (2.7.0)
    factory_girl (4.1.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0.0)
    factory_girl_rails (4.1.0)
      factory_girl (~> 4.1.0)
      railties (>= 3.0.0)
    faraday (0.12.2)
      multipart-post (>= 1.2, < 3)
    ffi (1.9.18-x86-mingw32)
    figaro (1.1.1)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    font-awesome-sass (5.0.6)
      sass (>= 3.2)
    formatador (0.2.5)
    friendly_id (5.2.3)
      activerecord (>= 4.0.0)
    globalid (0.4.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    gon (6.2.0)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      multi_json
      request_store (>= 1.0)
    guard (2.14.1)
      formatador (>= 0.2.4)
      listen (>= 2.7, < 4.0)
      lumberjack (~> 1.0)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      notiffany (~> 0.0)
      pry (>= 0.9.12)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
      thor (>= 0.18.1)
    guard-compat (1.2.1)
    guard-rspec (4.7.3)
      guard (~> 2.1)
      guard-compat (~> 1.1)
      rspec (>= 2.99.0, < 4.0)
    haml (5.0.4)
      temple (>= 0.8.0)
      tilt
    haml-rails (1.0.0)
      actionpack (>= 4.0.1)
      activesupport (>= 4.0.1)
      haml (>= 4.0.6, < 6.0)
      html2haml (>= 1.0.1)
      railties (>= 4.0.1)
    hashie (3.5.6)
    html2haml (2.2.0)
      erubis (~> 2.7.0)
      haml (>= 4.0, < 6)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6.0)
      ruby_parser (~> 3.5)
    http-cookie (1.0.3)
      domain_name (~> 0.5)
    i18n (0.9.0)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
    i18n_data (0.8.0)
    jmespath (1.3.1)
    jquery-rails (4.3.1)
      rails-dom-testing (>= 1, < 3)
      railties (>= 4.2.0)
      thor (>= 0.14, < 2.0)
    jquery-ui-rails (6.0.1)
      railties (>= 3.2.16)
    js_cookie_rails (2.2.0)
      railties (>= 3.1)
    json (2.1.0)
    jwt (1.5.6)
    launchy (2.4.3)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
    listen (3.1.5)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
      ruby_dep (~> 1.2)
    loofah (2.1.1)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    lumberjack (1.0.12)
    mail (2.7.0)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    meta_request (0.4.3)
      callsite (~> 0.0, >= 0.0.11)
      rack-contrib (>= 1.1, < 3)
      railties (>= 3.0.0, < 5.2.0)
    method_source (0.9.0)
    mime-types (3.1)
      mime-types-data (~> 3.2015)
    mime-types-data (3.2016.0521)
    mimemagic (0.3.2)
    mini_mime (0.1.4)
    mini_portile2 (2.3.0)
    minitest (5.10.3)
    modernizr-rails (2.7.1)
    money (6.13.0)
      i18n (>= 0.6.4, <= 2)
    multi_json (1.12.2)
    multi_xml (0.6.0)
    multipart-post (2.0.0)
    nenv (0.3.0)
    netrc (0.11.0)
    nio4r (2.1.0)
    nokogiri (1.8.1-x86-mingw32)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.3.0)
    notiffany (0.1.1)
      nenv (~> 0.1)
      shellany (~> 0.0)
    oauth (0.5.4)
    oauth2 (1.4.0)
      faraday (>= 0.8, < 0.13)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      multi_xml (~> 0.5)
      rack (>= 1.2, < 3)
    omniauth (1.7.1)
      hashie (>= 3.4.6, < 3.6.0)
      rack (>= 1.6.2, < 3)
    omniauth-facebook (4.0.0)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-google-oauth2 (0.2.10)
      addressable (~> 2.3)
      jwt (~> 1.0)
      multi_json (~> 1.3)
      omniauth (>= 1.1.1)
      omniauth-oauth2 (~> 1.3.1)
    omniauth-oauth (1.1.0)
      oauth
      omniauth (~> 1.0)
    omniauth-oauth2 (1.3.1)
      oauth2 (~> 1.0)
      omniauth (~> 1.2)
    omniauth-twitter (1.4.0)
      omniauth-oauth (~> 1.1)
      rack
    paperclip (5.2.1)
      activemodel (>= 4.2.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      cocaine (~> 0.5.5)
      mime-types
      mimemagic (~> 0.3.0)
    pg (0.21.0-x86-mingw32)
    pry (0.11.2)
      coderay (~> 1.1.0)
      method_source (~> 0.9.0)
    public_suffix (3.0.0)
    puma (3.11.0)
    rack (2.0.5)
    rack-contrib (1.2.0)
      rack (>= 0.9.1)
    rack-test (0.7.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (5.1.4)
      actioncable (= 5.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      actionview (= 5.1.4)
      activejob (= 5.1.4)
      activemodel (= 5.1.4)
      activerecord (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      bundler (>= 1.3.0)
      railties (= 5.1.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.0.3)
      loofah (~> 2.0)
    rails_12factor (0.0.3)
      rails_serve_static_assets
      rails_stdout_logging
    rails_real_favicon (0.0.7)
      json (>= 1.7, < 3)
      rails (>= 3.1)
      rest-client (~> 2.0)
      rubyzip (~> 1)
    rails_serve_static_assets (0.0.5)
    rails_stdout_logging (0.0.5)
    railties (5.1.4)
      actionpack (= 5.1.4)
      activesupport (= 5.1.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.8.7)
      thor (>= 0.18.1, < 2.0)
    rake (12.2.1)
    rb-fsevent (0.10.2)
    rb-inotify (0.9.10)
      ffi (>= 0.5.0, < 2)
    rb-notifu (0.0.4)
    recaptcha (4.6.2)
      json
    remotipart (1.4.0)
    request_store (1.3.2)
    rest-client (2.0.2-x86-mingw32)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
      http-cookie (>= 1.0.2, < 2.0)
      mime-types (>= 1.16, < 4.0)
      netrc (~> 0.8)
    rspec (3.7.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-core (3.7.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-expectations (3.7.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-mocks (3.7.0)
      diff-lcs (>= 1.2.0, < 2.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-rails (3.7.1)
      actionpack (>= 3.0)
      activesupport (>= 3.0)
      railties (>= 3.0)
      rspec-core (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-expectations (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-mocks (~> 3.7.0)
      rspec-support (~> 3.7.0)
    rspec-support (3.7.0)
    ruby_dep (1.5.0)
    ruby_parser (3.10.1)
      sexp_processor (~> 4.9)
    rubyzip (1.2.1)
    sass (3.5.3)
      sass-listen (~> 4.0.0)
    sass-listen (4.0.0)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.4)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.7)
    sass-rails (5.0.6)
      railties (>= 4.0.0, < 6)
      sass (~> 3.1)
      sprockets (>= 2.8, < 4.0)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0, < 4.0)
      tilt (>= 1.1, < 3)
    select2-rails (4.0.3)
      thor (~> 0.14)
    sexp_processor (4.10.0)
    shellany (0.0.1)
    sixarm_ruby_unaccent (1.2.0)
    sort_alphabetical (1.1.0)
      unicode_utils (>= 1.2.2)
    sprockets (3.7.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.1)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    sqlite3 (1.3.13-x86-mingw32)
    temple (0.8.0)
    thor (0.20.0)
    thread_safe (0.3.6)
    tilt (2.0.8)
    tzinfo (1.2.4)
      thread_safe (~> 0.1)
    tzinfo-data (1.2017.3)
      tzinfo (>= 1.0.0)
    uglifier (3.2.0)
      execjs (>= 0.3.0, < 3)
    unf (0.1.4)
      unf_ext
    unf_ext (0.0.7.4-x86-mingw32)
    unicode_utils (1.4.0)
    wdm (0.1.1)
    websocket-driver (0.6.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.2)
    will_paginate (3.1.6)
    xpath (2.1.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.3)

PLATFORMS
  x86-mingw32

DEPENDENCIES
  activemodel
  annotate
  audited
  aws-sdk (< 3.0)
  bcrypt (~> 3.1.12)
  better_errors
  binding_of_caller
  bootstrap-datepicker-rails
  bootstrap-sass
  bootstrap-will_paginate
  braintree
  capybara
  carrierwave
  certified
  chartkick
  cloudinary
  coffee-rails
  coffee-script-source (= 1.8.0)
  cookies_eu
  countries
  country_select (~> 3.1)
  data-confirm-modal
  factory_girl_rails (= 4.1.0)
  figaro
  font-awesome-sass (~> 5.0.6)
  friendly_id
  gon
  guard-rspec
  haml
  haml-rails
  jquery-rails
  jquery-ui-rails
  json
  launchy
  meta_request
  modernizr-rails
  omniauth-facebook
  omniauth-google-oauth2
  omniauth-twitter
  paperclip (~> 5.2.1)
  pg (~> 0.18)
  puma
  rails (= 5.1.4)
  rails_12factor
  rails_real_favicon
  rb-notifu
  recaptcha
  remotipart
  rspec-rails
  sass-rails
  select2-rails
  sprockets-rails
  sqlite3
  tzinfo-data
  uglifier (>= 1.0.3)
  wdm (>= 0.1.0)
  will_paginate (~> 3.1.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.3.3p222

BUNDLED WITH
   1.16.1
```

EDIT

I add my application.scss (not complete because it exceeds the number of chars):

```
/*
 *= require_tree .
 *= require_self
 *= require bootstrap-datepicker
 *= require jquery-ui
 *= require select2
 *= require select2-bootstrap
 */
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
//@import "bootstrap-responsive";
@import "welcome";
@import "users";
@import "sessions";
@import "extra_ejercicios";
@import "calendar";
@import "ejercicios";
@import "tablet";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import 'cookies_eu';
/* mixins, variables, etc. */

$grayMediumLight: #eaeaea;
$grayLighter: #fafafa;
$grayLight: #efefef;
$grayDarker: #303030;

@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* universal */
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 20px;
}

.no-padding{
  padding: 0 !important;
}
.no-margin{
  margin: 0 !important;
}

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

.center {
  text-align: center;
}

.hidden{
  display: none;
}

.rutinas {
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lightgray;
}
.rutinas-li{
  overflow: visible;
  padding: 10px 0;
  border-top: 2px solid lightgray;
}

.gravatar {
  @extend .img-rounded
}
...
```

And my application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery.remotipart
//= require jquery-ui
//= require_tree .
// Loads all Bootstrap javascripts
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-datepicker
//= require Chart.bundle
//= require chartkick
//= require select2
//= require data-confirm-modal
//= require cookies_eu

//This tells jQuery to send “text/javascript” in the request headers with every request (GET, POST, etc.).
//Rails will recognize this as a request for JSON and will respond accordingly.
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) { xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript") }
});

//http://samuelmullen.com/2011/02/dynamic-dropdowns-with-rails-jquery-and-ajax/
$.fn.subSelectWithAjax = function() {
    var that = this;

    this.change(function() {
        $.post(that.attr('rel'), {id: that.val()}, null, "script");
    });
};

$.fn.checkBoxAjax = function() {
    var that = this;

    this.change(function() {
        $.post(that.attr('rel'), {checked: that.is(':checked')}, null, "script");
    });
};

$.fn.verRutinaAjax = function() {
    var that = this;

    this.click(function(){
        $('.clicked').removeClass('clicked');
        $(this).addClass('clicked');
        var id = $(this).attr('usrid');
        $.post(that.attr('rel'), {id: id}, null, "script");
    });
};
```

Comment: Can you also post your full `Gemfile.lock` file?

Comment: Does this q and a help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394297/heroku-push-error-could-not-detect-rake-tasks/36394839

Comment: No, already tested

Comment: AFAIR, sass require node. Heroku only supports certain versions. You should check your node version. 

On the other hand, you could change from sass-rails to sassc-rails gem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up here by making the same mistake than you, believing that `“Could not detect rake tasks”` was the actual error where it was actually not, it's just the result of another error. In my case it was a Redis config failure*, so nothing to do with the loading of rake tasks.

If we look at the stack trace, the actual error is `LoadError: cannot load such file -- sass`, which is, if we look up more closely, triggered by this line : 
`font-awesome-sass-5.0.13/lib/font-awesome-sass.rb:48:in 'configure_sass'`
which comes from the `font-awesome-sass` gem.

This is a known issue for the gem that has been fixed in the `5.5.0.1` release of the gem (https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass/issues/168)

But in your Gemfile, you force the gem to stick to the `5.0.6` release. So replace this line in your Gemfile :
`gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.6'`
by this one to get the latest version of the gem :
`gem 'font-awesome-sass'` (Be sure that the latest version is compatible with your Rails version).

Also, as stated in the other answers, move the gems out of the `:assets` block as you're using Rails 5. Replacing `gem 'sass-rails'` with `gem 'sassc-rails'` may also fix issue of this kind.

*Hint if someone is ever landing here for the same problem than me, set `REDIS_PROVIDER = REDISCLOUD_URL` in the heroku env variables https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/1720

*Post edited on Apr. 7 to show only the working solution for OP.*

Comment: Yes, there is "config.assets.css_compressor = :sass" in my production.rb
I already tried your solution and it's not working neither. 
What is weird (at least for me) is that that code is built and running on Heroku (the last succesful push was made a year ago).

Comment: And do you use Sass ? What happens if you comment `config.assets.css_compressor = :sass` ?

Comment: I am considering stop using sass and remove it completely. 
Right now, if I remove "config.assets.css_compressor = :sass", the error keeps the same.

Comment: Ok actually the issue is not `sass` itself, but looks to come from the `font-awesome-sass` gem. Try commenting this line in your gemfile and see if the deployment works. It'll raise other issues, but at least you may identify where the issue comes from.
Comment this line : `gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.6'` (and run `bundle install`)

Comment: As another possible fix, try to replace the gem `gem 'sass-rails'` with `gem 'sassc-rails'`, and then `bundle install`

Comment: That's it! replacint `sass-rails` with `sassc-rails` didn't work, but commenting `font-awesome-sass` made it work. Now I get a SyntaxError, obviously. Is that version of the gem the problem, or the gem itself. I mean, do I need to find a replacement for the gem or just change the version?

Comment: Try by replacing `gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.0.6'` in your Gemfile by just `gem 'font-awesome-sass'` to get the latest version, that issue seems fixed in the `5.5.0.1` release (https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass/issues/168). If it triggers other compatibility issues, try to force it to this version `gem 'font-awesome-sass', '~> 5.5.0.1'`

Comment: Removing the version 5.0.6 solved the problem, please post the correct answer so I can mark it.

Comment: I edited this post to display the working answer :)

Answer (score 2):

remove `gem 'sass-rails'` from the `:assets` block

and place it above the line

```
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
```

This [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16406204/why-did-rails4-drop-support-for-assets-group-in-the-gemfile) explains why we no longer need the assets block after rails 4.

Also, make sure to rebundle and precompile your assets.
That means once you have changed the position of `gem 'sass-rails'` in your gemfile,
run

```
bundle install
```

then

```
RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

and then push again

Comment: I have already tried this and it's still not working. The error keeps exactly the same.

Comment: could you please add your application.css and application.js

Comment: also, did you removed the gem from the assets block?

Comment: I'll add them now.
And yes, I tried by removing it from the assets block.

Comment: In application.js add this line //= require_tree . at the end so that other requires are before this line.
Similarly in application.css, *= require_tree .   should be placed after *= require select2-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

This is probably and error with the  `stylesheet_link_tag` and `stylesheet_pack_tag`, check out your layout files probably you are including sass files and you are using `stylesheet_link_tag`, this is breaking your code given that as I understand you can just link plane css files. so if you are including sass files use the `stylesheet_pack_tag`

Comment: I have already tried this and it's still not working. The error keeps exactly the same.

Comment: could you share the repo that has the code? one easy solution that comes to my mind is to reset the database using `heroku run pg:reset` but this will delete all your db and will create it from scratch, then you can run `heroku run db:create db:migrate db:seed`