# Heroku-18 Stack upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-5

I am currently trying to upgrade to Heroku-18 Stack. I keep running into the same error.

```
remote:  !     Could not detect rake tasks
remote:  !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
remote:  !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
remote:  !     rake aborted!
remote:  !     NameError: uninitialized constant Mime::JSON
```

My gemfile is as follows:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.5.8"
#ruby "2.2.6"

gem 'activerecord-import'
gem "apns"

gem 'aws-sdk-v1'

gem 'braintree'
gem "bcrypt"#, git: "https://github.com/codahale/bcrypt-ruby/"

gem 'clockwork'
gem 'coffee-rails'

gem 'delayed_job_active_record'
gem 'dry-logic', '0.3.0'

gem 'execjs'

gem 'facets', :require => false

gem 'geocoder', '~> 1.3.4'
gem 'gcm'
gem 'google_directions'
gem 'google_distance_matrix', '~> 0.3.0'

gem "httparty"
gem 'houston'

gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'jquery-fileupload-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'libxml-ruby'
gem 'mail'
gem 'newrelic_rpm'
gem 'nokogiri'

gem 'phonelib'
gem 'pdfkit'
gem 'puma'
gem 'pubnub'
gem 'pg', '~>1.2.2'
gem 'prawn', '~> 1.2.1'
gem 'prawn-table', '~> 0.1.0'
gem 'pusher'

gem 'rails_12factor'
gem 'rails' , '6.0.0'
gem 'rack-timeout'
gem 'sass-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0.6'
gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'#, '~> 0.9.9.3'
gem 'wicked_pdf'

group :doc do
    # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
    gem 'sdoc', require: false
end
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This error does not seem specific.. Have you checked this thread : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394297/heroku-push-error-could-not-detect-rake-tasks/36394839

Comment: Hey, @Maxence Thanks for your response! I actually have seen those posts and tried those steps but still no luck. Not sure why the rakefile is not being detected. Prior to the EOL for cedar all everything was fine. Going from ruby 2.2.6 -> 2.5.8 and rails 4.0.2 -> 6.0.0 is the biggest change. Any suggestions would be appreciated!