# Heroku Refuses to Deploy

Tags: ruby, heroku, compilation

I simply don't understand what's happening. I was forced to update from Heroku-16 stack to Heroku-20 and now I'm at a loss. This is the deploy attempt

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.1.4
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
###### WARNING:
       Your app was upgraded to bundler 2.1.4.
       Previously you had a successful deploy with bundler 1.17.3.
       
       If you see problems related to the bundler version please refer to:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#known-upgrade-issues
       
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.6
       Purging Cache. Changing stack from cedar-14 to heroku-20
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.1.4
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
       rails (4.2.4) has dependency bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0), which is unsatisfied by the current bundler version 2.1.4, so the dependency is being ignored
       Fetching rake 13.0.3
       Installing rake 13.0.3
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
       Fetching json 1.8.6
       Fetching minitest 5.14.3
       Installing minitest 5.14.3
       Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
       Fetching builder 3.2.4
       Installing builder 3.2.4
       Fetching erubis 2.7.0
       Installing erubis 2.7.0
       Fetching racc 1.5.2
       Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
       Fetching crass 1.0.6
       Installing crass 1.0.6
       Fetching rack 1.6.13
       Installing rack 1.6.13
       Fetching mini_mime 1.0.2
       Installing mini_mime 1.0.2
       Fetching arel 6.0.4
       Installing arel 6.0.4
       Fetching public_suffix 4.0.6
       Installing public_suffix 4.0.6
       Fetching bcrypt 3.1.16
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.16 with native extensions
       Fetching bson 4.11.1
       Installing bson 4.11.1 with native extensions
       Fetching bson_ext 1.5.1
       Installing bson_ext 1.5.1 with native extensions
       Using bundler 2.1.4
       Fetching cancancan 3.2.1
       Installing cancancan 3.2.1
       Fetching numerizer 0.1.1
       Installing numerizer 0.1.1
       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Fetching execjs 2.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Fetching thor 1.1.0
       Installing thor 1.1.0
       Fetching connection_pool 2.2.3
       Installing connection_pool 2.2.3
       Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Fetching ffi 1.14.2
       Installing ffi 1.14.2 with native extensions
       Fetching htmlentities 4.3.4
       Installing htmlentities 4.3.4
       Fetching kgio 2.11.3
       Installing kgio 2.11.3 with native extensions
       Fetching origin 2.3.1
       Installing origin 2.3.1
       Fetching nio4r 2.5.4
       Installing nio4r 2.5.4 with native extensions
       Fetching raindrops 0.19.1
       Installing raindrops 0.19.1 with native extensions
       Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.4
       Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.4
       Fetching rdoc 4.3.0
       Installing rdoc 4.3.0
       Fetching redis 4.2.5
       Installing redis 4.2.5
       Fetching tilt 2.0.10
       Installing tilt 2.0.10
       Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Fetching wannabe_bool 0.7.1
       Installing wannabe_bool 0.7.1
       Fetching yajl-ruby 1.4.1
       Installing yajl-ruby 1.4.1 with native extensions
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.9
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.9
       Fetching i18n 0.9.5
       Installing i18n 0.9.5
       Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
       Installing rack-test 0.6.3
       Fetching warden 1.2.7
       Installing warden 1.2.7
       Fetching rack-cors 1.0.6
       Installing rack-cors 1.0.6
       Fetching rack-protection 1.5.5
       Installing rack-protection 1.5.5
       Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
       Installing sprockets 3.7.2
       Fetching mail 2.7.1
       Installing mail 2.7.1
       Fetching addressable 2.7.0
       Installing addressable 2.7.0
       Fetching nokogiri 1.11.1 (x86_64-linux)
       Installing nokogiri 1.11.1 (x86_64-linux)
       Fetching mongo 2.14.0
       Installing mongo 2.14.0
       Fetching chronic_duration 0.10.6
       Installing chronic_duration 0.10.6
       Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Fetching uglifier 4.2.0
       Installing uglifier 4.2.0
       Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
       Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
       Fetching sdoc 0.4.2
       Installing sdoc 0.4.2
       Fetching redis-store 1.9.0
       Installing redis-store 1.9.0
       Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
       Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
       Fetching puma 5.2.0
       Installing puma 5.2.0 with native extensions
       Fetching activesupport 4.2.4
       Installing activesupport 4.2.4
       Fetching sidekiq 5.2.8
       Installing sidekiq 5.2.8
       Fetching sinatra 1.4.8
       Installing sinatra 1.4.8
       Fetching css_parser 1.8.0
       Installing css_parser 1.8.0
       Fetching loofah 2.9.0
       Installing loofah 2.9.0
       Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
       Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
       Fetching redis-rack 2.0.6
       Installing redis-rack 2.0.6
       Fetching unicorn 5.8.0
       Installing unicorn 5.8.0 with native extensions
       Fetching rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Installing rails-deprecated_sanitizer 1.0.3
       Fetching globalid 0.4.2
       Installing globalid 0.4.2
       Fetching activemodel 4.2.4
       Installing activemodel 4.2.4
       Fetching jbuilder 2.9.1
       Installing jbuilder 2.9.1
       Fetching redis-activesupport 5.2.0
       Installing redis-activesupport 5.2.0
       Fetching sidekiq-status 1.1.4
       Installing sidekiq-status 1.1.4
       Fetching premailer 1.14.2
       Installing premailer 1.14.2
       Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
       Fetching sass 3.7.4
       Installing sass 3.7.4
       Fetching rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
       Installing rails-dom-testing 1.0.9
       Fetching activejob 4.2.4
       Installing activejob 4.2.4
       Fetching activerecord 4.2.4
       Installing activerecord 4.2.4
       Fetching mongoid 5.1.0
       Installing mongoid 5.1.0
       Fetching actionview 4.2.4
       Installing actionview 4.2.4
       Fetching mongoid-enum 0.4.0
       Installing mongoid-enum 0.4.0
       Fetching actionpack 4.2.4
       Installing actionpack 4.2.4
       Fetching actionmailer 4.2.4
       Installing actionmailer 4.2.4
       Fetching railties 4.2.4
       Installing railties 4.2.4
       Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Fetching redis-actionpack 5.1.0
       Installing redis-actionpack 5.1.0
       Fetching premailer-rails 1.11.1
       Installing premailer-rails 1.11.1
       Fetching coffee-rails 4.1.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.1.1
       Fetching responders 2.4.1
       Installing responders 2.4.1
       Fetching jquery-rails 4.4.0
       Installing jquery-rails 4.4.0
       Fetching rails 4.2.4
       Installing rails 4.2.4
       Fetching sass-rails 5.0.7
       Installing sass-rails 5.0.7
       Fetching redis-rails 5.0.2
       Installing redis-rails 5.0.2
       Fetching devise 4.7.3
       Installing devise 4.7.3
       Bundle complete! 27 Gemfile dependencies, 92 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Post-install message from sass:
       
       Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.
       
       * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
         primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
       
       * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
         sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
       
       * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
         https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
       
       Bundle completed (53.62s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks

 !
 !     Argument list too long -  logger -p user.notice -t "slugc[$$] "buildpack-ruby compile id=  framework=rails42 status=error finish=1612252273.48 elapsed=58.55 message=Argument\ list\ too\ long\ -\ \ logger\ -p\ user.notice\ -t\ \"slugc\[\$\$\]\"\ \"buildpack-ruby\ assets_precompile\ id\= \ framework\=rails42\ status\=error\ finish\=1612252273.34\ elapsed\=1.14\ message\=Could\\\ not\\\ detect\\\ rake\\\ tasks\''
 !     '\'ensure\\\ you\\\ can\\\ run\\\ \\\`\\\$\\\ bundle\\\ exec\\\ rake\\\ -P\\\`\\\ against\\\ your\\\ app\''
 !     '\'and\\\ using\\\ the\\\ production\\\ group\\\ of\\\ your\\\ Gemfile.\''
```

After using an older version of bundler I'm getting the same result.

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 1.17.3
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.6.6
   Purging Cache. Changing stack from cedar-14 to heroku-20
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 1.17.3
   Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 BUNDLE_GLOBAL_PATH_APPENDS_RUBY_SCOPE=1 bundle install -j4
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
   Fetching rake 13.0.3
   Installing rake 13.0.3
   Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
   Fetching json 1.8.6
   Fetching minitest 5.14.3
   Installing minitest 5.14.3
   Installing json 1.8.6 with native extensions
   Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
   Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
   Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
   Fetching builder 3.2.4
   Installing builder 3.2.4
   Fetching erubis 2.7.0
   Installing erubis 2.7.0
   Fetching mini_portile2 2.5.0
   Installing mini_portile2 2.5.0
   Fetching racc 1.5.2
   Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
   Fetching crass 1.0.6
   Installing crass 1.0.6
   Fetching rack 1.6.13
   Installing rack 1.6.13
   Fetching mini_mime 1.0.2
   Installing mini_mime 1.0.2
   Fetching arel 6.0.4
   Installing arel 6.0.4
   Fetching public_suffix 4.0.6
   Installing public_suffix 4.0.6
   Fetching bcrypt 3.1.16
   Installing bcrypt 3.1.16 with native extensions
   Fetching bson 4.11.1
   Installing bson 4.11.1 with native extensions
   Fetching bson_ext 1.5.1
   Installing bson_ext 1.5.1 with native extensions
   Using bundler 1.17.3
   Fetching cancancan 3.2.1
   Installing cancancan 3.2.1
   Fetching numerizer 0.1.1
   Installing numerizer 0.1.1
   Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
   Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
   Fetching execjs 2.7.0
   Installing execjs 2.7.0
   Fetching thor 1.1.0
   Installing thor 1.1.0
   Fetching connection_pool 2.2.3
   Installing connection_pool 2.2.3
   Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
   Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
   Fetching ffi 1.14.2
   Installing ffi 1.14.2 with native extensions
   Fetching htmlentities 4.3.4
   Installing htmlentities 4.3.4
   Fetching kgio 2.11.3
   Installing kgio 2.11.3 with native extensions
   Fetching origin 2.3.1
   Installing origin 2.3.1
   Fetching nio4r 2.5.4
   Installing nio4r 2.5.4 with native extensions
   Fetching raindrops 0.19.1
   Installing raindrops 0.19.1 with native extensions
   Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.4
   Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.4
   Fetching rdoc 4.3.0
   Installing rdoc 4.3.0
   Fetching redis 4.2.5
   Installing redis 4.2.5
   Fetching tilt 2.0.10
   Installing tilt 2.0.10
   Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
   Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
   Fetching wannabe_bool 0.7.1
   Installing wannabe_bool 0.7.1
   Fetching yajl-ruby 1.4.1
   Installing yajl-ruby 1.4.1 with native extensions
   Fetching tzinfo 1.2.9
   Installing tzinfo 1.2.9
   Fetching i18n 0.9.5
   Installing i18n 0.9.5
   Fetching rack-test 0.6.3
   Installing rack-test 0.6.3
   Fetching warden 1.2.7
   Installing warden 1.2.7
   Fetching rack-cors 1.0.6
   Installing rack-cors 1.0.6
   Fetching rack-protection 1.5.5
   Installing rack-protection 1.5.5
   Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
   Installing sprockets 3.7.2
   Fetching mail 2.7.1
   Installing mail 2.7.1
   Fetching addressable 2.7.0
   Installing addressable 2.7.0
   Fetching nokogiri 1.11.1 (x86_64-linux)
   Installing nokogiri 1.11.1 (x86_64-linux)
   Fetching mongo 2.14.0
   Installing mongo 2.14.0
   Fetching chronic_duration 0.10.6
   Installing chronic_duration 0.10.6
   Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
   Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
   Fetching uglifier 4.2.0
   Installing uglifier 4.2.0
   Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
   Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
   Fetching sdoc 0.4.2
   Installing sdoc 0.4.2
   Fetching redis-store 1.9.0
   Installing redis-store 1.9.0
   Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
   Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
   Fetching puma 5.2.0
   Installing puma 5.2.0 with native extensions
   Fetching activesupport 4.2.4
   Installing activesupport 4.2.4
   Fetching sidekiq 5.2.8
   Installing sidekiq 5.2.8
   Fetching sinatra 1.4.8
   Installing sinatra 1.4.8
   Fetching css_parser 1.8.0
   Installing css_parser 1.8.0...
   
   ...Bundle complete! 28 Gemfile dependencies, 93 gems now installed.
   Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
   Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
   Post-install message from sass:
   
   Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.
   
   * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
     primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
   
   * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
     sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
   
   * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
     https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
   
   Bundle completed (55.97s)
   Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
 !
 !     Argument list too long -  logger -p user.notice -t "slugc[$$]" "buildpack-ruby compile id=48c423c89ef framework=rails42 status=error finish=1612402346.31 elapsed=61.14 message=Argument\ list\ too\ long\ -\ \ logger\ -p\ user.notice\ -t\ \"slugc\[\$\$\]\"\ \"buildpack-ruby\ assets_precompile\ id\=48c423c89ef\ framework\=rails42\ status\=error\ finish\=1612402346.17\ elapsed\=1.14\ message\=Could\\\ not\\\ detect\\\ rake\\\ tasks\''
 !     '\'ensure\\\ you\\\ can\\\ run\\\ \\\`\\\$\\\ bundle\\\ exec\\\ rake\\\ -P\\\`\\\ against\\\ your\\\ app\''
 !     '\'and\\\ using\\\ the\\\ production\\\ group\\\ of\\\ your\\\ Gemfile.\''
 !     '\'/tmp/build_eb6a7787_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/object/duplicable.rb:85:\\\ warning:\\\ BigDecimal.new\\\ is\\\ deprecated\\\;\\\ use\\\ BigDecimal\\\(\\\)\\\ method\\\ instead.\''
 !     '\'/tmp/build_eb6a7787_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121:\\\ warning:\\\ constant\\\ ::Fixnum\\\ is\\\ deprecated\''
 !     '\'/tmp/build_eb6a7787_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:121:\\\ warning:\\\ constant\\\ ::Bignum\\\ is\\\ deprecated\''
 !     '\'rake\\\ aborted\\\!\''
 !     '\'SystemStackError:\\\ stack\\\ level\\\ too\\\ deep\''
 !     '\'/tmp/build_eb6a7787_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:125:in\\\ \\\`block\\\ \\\(2\\\ levels\\\)\\\ in\\\ \\\<class:Numeric\\\>\\\'\''
 !     '\'/tmp/build_eb6a7787_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in\\\ \\\`block\\\ \\\(2\\\ levels\\\)\\\ in\\\ \\\<class:Numeric\\\>\\\'\''
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.4/lib/active_support/core_ext/numeric/conversions.rb:131:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Numeric>'
!    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson/integer.rb:54:in `block in <module:Integer>'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson/integer.rb:53:in `initialize'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson/integer.rb:53:in `new'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson/integer.rb:53:in `<module:Integer>'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson/integer.rb:23:in `<module:BSON>'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson/integer.rb:15:in `<top (required)>'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson.rb:66:in `require'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bson-4.11.1/lib/bson.rb:66:in `<top (required)>'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo.rb:32:in `require'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mongo-2.14.0/lib/mongo.rb:32:in `<top (required)>'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-5.1.0/lib/mongoid.rb:16:in `require'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/mongoid-5.1.0/lib/mongoid.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `require'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in require'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `each'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in `block in require'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `each'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:65:in `require'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/bundler-1.17.3/lib/bundler.rb:114:in `require'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/config/application.rb:16:in `<top (required)>'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/Rakefile:4:in `require'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/Rakefile:4:in `<top (required)>'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:29:in `load_rakefile'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:703:in `raw_load_rakefile'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:104:in `block in load_rakefile'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:103:in `load_rakefile'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:82:in `block in run'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:186:in `standard_exception_handling'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/gems/rake-13.0.3/lib/rake/application.rb:80:in `run'
 !    /tmp/build_9f8bd6e2_/bin/rake:9:in `<main>'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1106:in `rake'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in `log'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:72:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1127:in `allow_git'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:109:in `block in compile'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:94:in `compile'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:62:in `block in compile'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:60:in `compile'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:35:in `block in compile'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:34:in `compile'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in `log'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-20/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Answer (score 0):

> rails (4.2.4) has dependency bundler (>= 1.3.0, < 2.0), which is unsatisfied by the current bundler version 2.1.4, so the dependency is being ignored`

That suggests your app need an older version of Bundler.

Check out Heroku Doc [Using an older version of Bundler](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version#using-an-older-version-of-bundler)
.

Update:

> Could\\ not\\ detect\\ rake\\ tasks

That indicates [Rake tasks cannot be detected](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/841), check out another questoin: [heroku push error: “Could not detect rake tasks”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394297/heroku-push-error-could-not-detect-rake-tasks)

Comment: Now bundler got through with no warning but the outcome is exactly the same

Comment: Error log `message\=Could\\\ not\\\ detect\\\ rake\\\ tasks\''` indicates: [Rails Application deploys now fail to build when Rake tasks cannot be detected](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/841), [heroku push error: “Could not detect rake tasks”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394297/heroku-push-error-could-not-detect-rake-tasks),