# Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app, Push failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried to deploy to heroku and gave this error, I'm using PostgreSQL. Please help me!!

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-18 stack
-----> Ruby app detected
-----> Installing bundler 2.1.4
-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock
-----> Compiling Ruby/Rails
-----> Using Ruby version: ruby-2.5.1
-----> Installing dependencies using bundler 2.1.4
       Running: BUNDLE_WITHOUT='development:test' BUNDLE_PATH=vendor/bundle BUNDLE_BIN=vendor/bundle/bin BUNDLE_DEPLOYMENT=1 bundle install -j4
       The dependency byebug (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for x86_64-linux but the dependency is only for ruby, x86-mingw32, x64-mingw32. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform ruby x86-mingw32 x64-mingw32`.
       The dependency tzinfo-data (>= 0) will be unused by any of the platforms Bundler is installing for. Bundler is installing for x86_64-linux but the dependency is only for x86-mingw32, x86-mswin32, x64-mingw32, java. To add those platforms to the bundle, run `bundle lock --add-platform x86-mingw32 x86-mswin32 x64-mingw32 java`.
       Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/............
       Fetching rake 13.0.3
       Installing rake 13.0.3
       Fetching concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
       Fetching minitest 5.14.3
       Fetching thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing minitest 5.14.3
       Installing thread_safe 0.3.6
       Installing concurrent-ruby 1.1.8
       Fetching builder 3.2.4
       Installing builder 3.2.4
       Fetching erubi 1.10.0
       Installing erubi 1.10.0
       Fetching racc 1.5.2
       Installing racc 1.5.2 with native extensions
       Fetching crass 1.0.6
       Installing crass 1.0.6
       Fetching rack 2.2.3
       Installing rack 2.2.3
       Fetching nio4r 2.5.4
       Installing nio4r 2.5.4 with native extensions
       Fetching websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Installing websocket-extensions 0.1.5
       Fetching mini_mime 1.0.2
       Installing mini_mime 1.0.2
       Fetching arel 9.0.0
       Installing arel 9.0.0
       Fetching mimemagic 0.3.5
       Installing mimemagic 0.3.5
       Fetching execjs 2.7.0
       Installing execjs 2.7.0
       Fetching rb-fsevent 0.10.4
       Installing rb-fsevent 0.10.4
       Fetching ffi 1.14.2
       Installing ffi 1.14.2 with native extensions
       Fetching bcrypt 3.1.16
       Installing bcrypt 3.1.16 with native extensions
       Fetching msgpack 1.3.3
       Installing msgpack 1.3.3 with native extensions
       Using bundler 2.1.4
       Fetching coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Installing coffee-script-source 1.12.2
       Fetching method_source 1.0.0
       Installing method_source 1.0.0
       Fetching thor 1.1.0
       Installing thor 1.1.0
       Fetching orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Installing orm_adapter 0.5.0
       Fetching pg 1.2.3
       Installing pg 1.2.3 with native extensions
       Fetching puma 3.12.6
       Installing puma 3.12.6 with native extensions
       Fetching tilt 2.0.10
       Installing tilt 2.0.10
       Fetching turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Installing turbolinks-source 5.2.0
       Fetching tzinfo 1.2.9
       Installing tzinfo 1.2.9
       Fetching rack-test 1.1.0
       Installing rack-test 1.1.0
       Fetching warden 1.2.9
       Installing warden 1.2.9
       Fetching i18n 1.8.7
       Installing i18n 1.8.7
       Fetching sprockets 3.7.2
       Installing sprockets 3.7.2
       Fetching websocket-driver 0.7.3
       Installing websocket-driver 0.7.3 with native extensions
       Fetching mail 2.7.1
       Installing mail 2.7.1
       Fetching marcel 0.3.3
       Installing marcel 0.3.3
       Fetching autoprefixer-rails 10.2.0.0
       Installing autoprefixer-rails 10.2.0.0
       Fetching uglifier 4.2.0
       Installing uglifier 4.2.0
       Fetching nokogiri 1.11.1 (x86_64-linux)
       Installing nokogiri 1.11.1 (x86_64-linux)
       Fetching rb-inotify 0.10.1
       Installing rb-inotify 0.10.1
       Fetching coffee-script 2.4.1
       Installing coffee-script 2.4.1
       Fetching bootsnap 1.5.1
       Installing bootsnap 1.5.1 with native extensions
       Fetching turbolinks 5.2.1
       Installing turbolinks 5.2.1
       Fetching activesupport 5.2.4.4
       Installing activesupport 5.2.4.4
       Fetching loofah 2.9.0
       Installing loofah 2.9.0
       Fetching sass-listen 4.0.0
       Installing sass-listen 4.0.0
       Fetching rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Installing rails-dom-testing 2.0.3
       Fetching globalid 0.4.2
       Fetching activemodel 5.2.4.4
       Installing globalid 0.4.2
       Installing activemodel 5.2.4.4
       Fetching jbuilder 2.10.1
       Installing jbuilder 2.10.1
       Fetching rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
       Fetching sass 3.7.4
       Installing rails-html-sanitizer 1.3.0
       Fetching activejob 5.2.4.4
       Installing sass 3.7.4
       Installing activejob 5.2.4.4
       Fetching activerecord 5.2.4.4
       Fetching actionview 5.2.4.4
       Installing activerecord 5.2.4.4
       Installing actionview 5.2.4.4
       Fetching bootstrap-sass 3.3.4.1
       Installing bootstrap-sass 3.3.4.1
       Fetching actionpack 5.2.4.4
       Installing actionpack 5.2.4.4
       Fetching adminlte2-rails 0.0.6
       Fetching actioncable 5.2.4.4
       Fetching actionmailer 5.2.4.4
       Installing actionmailer 5.2.4.4
       Installing actioncable 5.2.4.4
       Fetching activestorage 5.2.4.4
       Installing activestorage 5.2.4.4
       Fetching railties 5.2.4.4
       Installing adminlte2-rails 0.0.6
       Installing railties 5.2.4.4
       Fetching sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Installing sprockets-rails 3.2.2
       Fetching coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Fetching responders 3.0.1
       Installing coffee-rails 4.2.2
       Installing responders 3.0.1
       Fetching rails 5.2.4.4
       Fetching sass-rails 5.1.0
       Installing rails 5.2.4.4
       Installing sass-rails 5.1.0
       Fetching devise 4.7.3
       Installing devise 4.7.3
       Bundle complete! 20 Gemfile dependencies, 68 gems now installed.
       Gems in the groups development and test were not installed.
       Bundled gems are installed into `./vendor/bundle`
       Post-install message from i18n:
       
       HEADS UP! i18n 1.1 changed fallbacks to exclude default locale.
       But that may break your application.
       
       If you are upgrading your Rails application from an older version of Rails:
       
       Please check your Rails app for 'config.i18n.fallbacks = true'.
       If you're using I18n (>= 1.1.0) and Rails (< 5.2.2), this should be
       'config.i18n.fallbacks = [I18n.default_locale]'.
       If not, fallbacks will be broken in your app by I18n 1.1.x.
       
       If you are starting a NEW Rails application, you can ignore this notice.
       
       For more info see:
       https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/releases/tag/v1.1.0
       
       Post-install message from sass:
       
       Ruby Sass has reached end-of-life and should no longer be used.
       
       * If you use Sass as a command-line tool, we recommend using Dart Sass, the new
         primary implementation: https://sass-lang.com/install
       
       * If you use Sass as a plug-in for a Ruby web framework, we recommend using the
         sassc gem: https://github.com/sass/sassc-ruby#readme
       
       * For more details, please refer to the Sass blog:
         https://sass-lang.com/blog/posts/7828841
       
       Bundle completed (35.36s)
       Cleaning up the bundler cache.
-----> Installing node-v12.16.2-linux-x64
-----> Detecting rake tasks
 !
 !     Could not detect rake tasks
 !     ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
 !     and using the production group of your Gemfile.
 !     /tmp/build_e8ec4900_/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)
 !     from /tmp/build_e8ec4900_/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
 !     from /tmp/build_e8ec4900_/bin/rake:7:in `require_relative'
 !     from /tmp/build_e8ec4900_/bin/rake:7:in `<main>'
 !
/tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/helpers/rake_runner.rb:106:in `load_rake_tasks!': Could not detect rake tasks (LanguagePack::Helpers::RakeRunner::CannotLoadRakefileError)
ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app
and using the production group of your Gemfile.
/tmp/build_e8ec4900_/config/boot.rb:4:in `require': cannot load such file -- bootsnap/setup (LoadError)
    from /tmp/build_e8ec4900_/config/boot.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /tmp/build_e8ec4900_/bin/rake:7:in `require_relative'
    from /tmp/build_e8ec4900_/bin/rake:7:in `<main>'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1106:in `rake'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:78:in `block (2 levels) in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in `log'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:72:in `block in run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:71:in `run_assets_precompile_rake_task'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:116:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:1127:in `allow_git'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:109:in `block in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/ruby.rb:94:in `compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:62:in `block in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails2.rb:60:in `compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:42:in `block in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails3.rb:41:in `compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:35:in `block in compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:50:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:46:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/rails4.rb:34:in `compile'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:20:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/base.rb:190:in `log'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:19:in `block in <main>'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `block in trace'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:18:in `block (2 levels) in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:40:in `yield_with_block_depth'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:17:in `block in instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/vendor/ruby/heroku-18/lib/ruby/2.6.0/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:16:in `instrument'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/lib/language_pack/instrument.rb:35:in `trace'
    from /tmp/codon/tmp/buildpacks/50d5eddf222a9b7326028041d4e6509f915ccf2c/bin/support/ruby_compile:15:in `<main>'
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.
 !     Push failed
```

Comment: "ensure you can run `$ bundle exec rake -P` against your app"

Comment: `-----> Removing BUNDLED WITH version in the Gemfile.lock` suggests you have the wrong version of Bundler configured. Do [the answers here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36394297/heroku-push-error-could-not-detect-rake-tasks) help? Be careful with your [Bundler version on Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/bundler-version).