# Rails 7 Ruby 3.1 LoadError: cannot load such file -- net/smtp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-7, ruby-3.1

I upgraded to Rails 7 and Ruby 3.1. While trying to run tests with `rspec` I got the error below. How can I fix it?

```
An error occurred while loading rails_helper.
Failure/Error: require File.expand_path('../config/environment', __dir__)

LoadError:
  cannot load such file -- net/smtp
# .../gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail.rb:9:in `<module:Mail>'
# .../gems/mail-2.7.1/lib/mail.rb:3:in `<main>'
# .../bundler/gems/rails-6a0f6c4d70b1/actionmailbox/lib/action_mailbox/mail_ext.rb:3:in `<main>'
# .../bundler/gems/rails-6a0f6c4d70b1/actionmailbox/lib/action_mailbox.rb:3:in `<main>'
# .../bundler/gems/rails-6a0f6c4d70b1/actionmailbox/lib/action_mailbox/engine.rb:9:in `<main>'
# ./config/application.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `require_relative'
# ./config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `require'
# ./spec/rails_helper.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
```

(bootsnap and zeitwerk is excluded from backtrace)

Answer (score 163, accepted):

## For Rails 6

Add `gem 'net-smtp', require: false` to your *Gemfile* and run `bundle`.

Similarly I assume you may have problems with `net-imap` and `net-pop` and so have to add them [until](https://github.com/mikel/mail/pull/1472#issuecomment-1165161541) a new `mail` gem version is released.

```
gem 'net-smtp', require: false
gem 'net-imap', require: false
gem 'net-pop', require: false
```

**UPD:** The mail gem version 2.8.0 was released on December 3rd, 2022 which includes the fix. Just upgrade to >= 2.8.0.

## For Rails 7

On January 6th, 2022 Rails 7.0.1 was [released](https://rubyonrails.org/2022/1/6/Rails-7-0-1-has-been-released):

> The focus of this release is bring support to Ruby 3.1

Amongh other Ruby 3.1-related issues it brought [a fix](https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/cb44df700d04f144917b5083910c3dfde6179dbf) for this problem. So **upgrade to Rails >= 7.0.1**.

---

Related pull requests and issues:

- [mikel/mail: Add former default gems as a dependency for Ruby 3.1 compatibility](https://github.com/mikel/mail/pull/1439)
- [Add net/smtp gem for bug report templates to support Ruby 3.1](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42366)

Comment: I got this just by upgrading Ruby and Puma and the above fix worked.

Comment: I had this problem with the "pony" gem, and this fixed it for me.

Comment: Upgrading from 6.0.x to rails 6.1.x and had a problem I added all three gems as require false and my production site worked. Thank you!

Comment: I had to also include `net-ftp`

Answer (score 14):

I met the same problem when running Rails in production mode.  ( Ruby 3, Rails 6.1 )

copy and paste this lines of code to `Gemfile`:

```
gem 'net-smtp', require: false
gem 'net-imap', require: false
gem 'net-pop', require: false
```